# Array push function result

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone help me with this?

The array always return blank.

```
var x = [];
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, res) {
x.push(res)
});
console.log(x);
```

/* The result( res ) of the function is a Array....

Answer (score -1):

`geocoder.geocode()` runs asynchronously.

Is this more what you're looking for?

```
var x = [];
geocoder.geocode('29 champs elysée paris', function(err, res) {
    x.push(res)
    console.log(x);
});
```

If you need to examine the array after several different `geocoder.geocode()` executions (or other asynchronous executions) you'd need some other infrastructure to handle that. Research asynchronous functions a bit to find examples on that.